# Setting min width for value 0 amcharts column series with bullet labels

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

In Following example I've stacked column series with bullet labels on it. But as you can see in example there are few `0` values too. I am trying to set some minimum width to series so that bullet label is visible even if value is smaller or `0`.

As you can see in series for year `2017`, it starts with `0`. But the label is not visible completely.

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "year": "2016",
  "europe": 1.5,
  "namerica": 1.5,
  "asia": 1.1,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.2,
  "africa": 0
}, {
  "year": "2017",
  "europe": 0,
  "namerica": 1.7,
  "asia": 1.2,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.3,
  "africa": 0.1
}, {
  "year": "2018",
  "europe": 1.8,
  "namerica": 1.9,
  "asia": 0,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.3,
  "africa": 0.1
}];

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "right";

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.opacity = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.opacity = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.stroke = am4core.color("#495C43");
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 10;
valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 40;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueX = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryY = "year";
  series.stacked = true;
  series.name = name;
  
  series.minWidth = `100px`;
  
  var labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  labelBullet.locationX = 0.5;
  labelBullet.label.text = "{valueX}";
  labelBullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
}

createSeries("europe", "Europe");
createSeries("namerica", "North America");
createSeries("asia", "Asia");
createSeries("lamerica", "Latin America");
createSeries("meast", "Middle East");
createSeries("africa", "Africa");

chart.legend.position = 'bottom';
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to specify a minimum width/height (depending on axis rotation) as the column size is directly related to its data; setting a minimum size would misrepresent the column values in your chart.

A better solution is to hide the labels that don't fit by setting `hideOversized` to true on the label bullets and use tooltips instead with a chart cursor.

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "year": "2016",
  "europe": 1.5,
  "namerica": 1.5,
  "asia": 1.1,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.2,
  "africa": 0
}, {
  "year": "2017",
  "europe": 0,
  "namerica": 1.7,
  "asia": 1.2,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.3,
  "africa": 0.1
}, {
  "year": "2018",
  "europe": 1.8,
  "namerica": 1.9,
  "asia": 0,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.3,
  "africa": 0.1
}];

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "right";

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.opacity = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.opacity = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.stroke = am4core.color("#495C43");
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 10;
valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 40;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueX = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryY = "year";
  series.stacked = true;
  series.name = name;
  series.tooltipText = "{name}: {valueX}";
  
  var labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  labelBullet.label.hideOversized = true;
  labelBullet.locationX = 0.5;
  labelBullet.label.text = "{valueX}";
  labelBullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
}

createSeries("europe", "Europe");
createSeries("namerica", "North America");
createSeries("asia", "Asia");
createSeries("lamerica", "Latin America");
createSeries("meast", "Middle East");
createSeries("africa", "Africa");

chart.legend.position = 'bottom';
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer gives a different approach or you can may be shift the label a bit like so.

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "year": "2016",
  "europe": 1.5,
  "namerica": 1.5,
  "asia": 1.1,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.2,
  "africa": 0
}, {
  "year": "2017",
  "europe": 0,
  "namerica": 1.7,
  "asia": 1.2,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.3,
  "africa": 0.1
}, {
  "year": "2018",
  "europe": 1.8,
  "namerica": 1.9,
  "asia": 0,
  "lamerica": 0.3,
  "meast": 0.3,
  "africa": 0.1
}];

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "right";

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.opacity = 0;

var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.opacity = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.stroke = am4core.color("#495C43");
valueAxis.renderer.ticks.template.length = 10;
valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 40;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueX = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryY = "year";
  series.stacked = true;
  series.name = name;
  
  series.minWidth = `100px`;
  
  var labelBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  labelBullet.locationX = 0.5;
  labelBullet.label.text = "{valueX}";
  labelBullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
  labelBullet.label.x= 4;
}

createSeries("europe", "Europe");
createSeries("namerica", "North America");
createSeries("asia", "Asia");
createSeries("lamerica", "Latin America");
createSeries("meast", "Middle East");
createSeries("africa", "Africa");

chart.legend.position = 'bottom';
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this. But this does not give proper output. Imagine having 2  0's in a row one after another.